# Call autofilter criteria by index instead of by name

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to apply autofilter criteria by index instead of name? Currently, if I want to filter column F by "apple", my code would be:

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="apple"
```

However, I just want criteria to be the first item that appears in the autofilter drop down. Something like a `Criteria1:= 1`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The values in the dropdown are sorted. While there is no direct access you could create a sorted dictionary and use the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first item that would be used for your filter criteria.

**Requirements:**

Requires `.Net` to be installed as I use the `.Net` [SortedList](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_sortedlist.php) class; accessed, via the `.Net` framework, through `System.Collections`.

**Using a dictionary or collection instead of a sorted list:**

Easy enough to see how to amend this for a dictionary or collection which is sorted.

If you are thinking about sorting a dictionary or collection (as per @Jeeped's comment) you could review Chip Pearson's [sorting functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm) .

**Using a different column to get first drop down item:**

Alter the following two variables

1) `targetColumn` to which ever column you are interested in e.g. "A","B" ....

2) `headerRow` to whichever row your header is in e.g.row 1,2.....

**Your example:**

Now, I have added this line:

```
 targetSheet.Range("F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=GetFilterCriteria(targetValues)
```

So you can see how it might work in the example you gave. But, this does require your data to start in column F, as you are filtering on the first field.

**Example run of code:**

[image: Filtering range]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testCall()

    Dim targetBook As Workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set targetBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set targetSheet = targetBook.Worksheets("Data")

    Const targetColumn As String = "F" 'this could be shifted to local variables
    Const headerRow As Long = 1

    Dim endRow As Long

    endRow = GetLastRow(targetSheet, targetColumn)

    If endRow < 2 Then

        MsgBox "No data to filter below header row in target column"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim targetValues()

    targetValues = targetSheet.Range(targetColumn & headerRow + 1 & ":" & targetColumn & endRow).Value

    Dim filterCriteria As String

    filterCriteria = GetFilterCriteria(targetValues)

    MsgBox "Your filter criteria for column " & targetColumn & " is " & GetFilterCriteria(targetValues)

    targetSheet.Range("F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=GetFilterCriteria(targetValues)

End Sub
Public Function GetFilterCriteria(ByRef targetValues As Variant) As String 'this will become a function returning a string , accepting a range as parameter

    Dim orderedList As Object
    Set orderedList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList") 'requires .Net framework installed. Otherwise order a dictionary or collection.See here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm

    Dim currentItem As Long

    On Error Resume Next                         'so ignore if item already in list

    For currentItem = LBound(targetValues, 1) To UBound(targetValues, 1)

        orderedList.Add targetValues(currentItem, 1), targetValues(currentItem, 1)

    Next currentItem

    On Error GoTo 0

    GetFilterCriteria = orderedList.GetByIndex(0)

End Function
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal targetColumn As String) As Long

   GetLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, targetColumn).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```